# Python Django-Rest-Framework update user on data creation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Assuming I have 2 models, one User, the other Post. A user can create posts. A user has a field called 'exp_pts' as an IntegerField. This is meant to increment by say 30 when the user creates a post.

I assume I would have to use the create() method in the PostSerializer. This is my current serializer for Posts (currently not working due to the create() method not working as intended)

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'kingdom', 'post_type', 'file_path',
                  'title', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['user'] = SimpleUserSerializer(
            User.objects.get(pk=data['user'])).data
        data['kingdom'] = KingdomSerializer(
            Kingdom.objects.get(pk=data['kingdom'])).data
        return data

    # This is not yet working
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.pop('user')
        user.exp_pts += 30
        user.save()
        return user
```

What is a way to do the above? If the create() method isn't adequate then what other way is there to achieve this? Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `create` method is wrong. It should be more like that:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.pop('user')
        user.exp_pts += 30
        user.save()

        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Your serializer's `create` method has to return an instance of the created `Post`, not `User`. Since the actual creation can be handled by DRF itself, just return `super().create(validated_data)`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I see what you mean, however this is still giving this error:django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_post.user_id

Comment: ah, your `post` model has a user FK. then dont `pop` the the user from the dict, but `get` it.

Comment: replacing 'pop' with 'get' did it. Thank you